# ERREUR: une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « field_id »

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to migrate a module from odoo 10 to odoo 12 that contains a view with ir.default module type. but it shows me this error:

I do not know how to rectify it. Can anyone help me, please?

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « field_id »
DETAIL:  La ligne en échec contient (9, null, null, null, null, null, 1, 2019-04-09 14:57:31.803622, 1, 2019-04-09 14:57:31.803622)
" while parsing /PycharmProjects/Odoo12/bank_reconciliation/views/account_selected_move_line.xml:32, near
<record model="ir.default" id="action_selected_account_move_line_values">
            <field name="name">Sélectionner les écritures</field>
            <field name="field_id"/>
            <field name="key">action</field>
            <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
            <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('action_selected_account_move_line'))"/>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_account_move_line"/>
            <field name="object" eval="True"/>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no value for `field_id` in your xml record. Default values are always set for model fields. So get the field xml/external ID and set it. The external IDs of fields are generated:

```
module.field_model__fieldname
```

So for example for model `sale.order` the field `name` which is first implemented in module `sale` it's `sale.field_sale_order__name`.

Edit: Your xml record is plain wrong for model `ir.default`, it looks like the old model `ir.values`. I found just one example for creating `ir.default` records by xml:

```xml
<function id="purchase_default_set"
    model="ir.default" name="set"
    eval="('purchase.requisition', 'warehouse_id', ref('stock.warehouse0'))"/>
```

This example is from module `purchase_requistion` and creates a default value for model `purchase.requisition` on field `ẁarehouse_id` with value "ID of record behind external ID 'stock.warehouse0'" (which is the default warehouse when installing app stock.

You just have to adapt this to your wanted default value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I don't really understand when should I add it. Should I do like this: <field name="model">module.field_model__fieldname</field>

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer again. I also found this function in the way addons/purchase_requisition/data/purchase_requisition_data.xml. But this function only shows us that ir.values ​​no longer exists in odoo 12 and also set_default becomes set. I can not adapt this formula in creating my view. Can you help me and tell me the structure how it should be to create <record model="ir.default" ....>

Comment: Maybe you should try to write a question with all relative code and a little description what it does in which Odoo and in which Odoo version it shall be migrated. I know there is already one but without enough infornation.

Comment: Thanks @CZoellner for your reply. I have made an update on my question. I want to migrate from 10 to 12